# Where is my new Gnome 3.10 software?

Tags: gnome, ppa

After upgrading to Gnome 3.10 via the Gnome3 and Gnome3-staging I don't see the new software center, maps or any of the new software jazz that is suppose to come with Gnome 3.10. I see the window and top menu changes and It states I am running Gnome 3.10 in the system details app.

So where are my new apps that are supposed to be part of Gnome 3.10? as seen [here](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.10/)

Comment: Did you install `gnome-core-apps`?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you follow the steps as mentioned in http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html. The Gnome 3.10 ppa seems to contain bugs.

Comment: @Frank installing the ppa gnome3-next caused things to shatter and isnt an "official" ppa from gnome. so I ignored that part. mmstick I assume thats just a `sudo apt-get`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think packages for all the new apps that you have mentioned are available in the gnome ppas, so far I have seen only the following.

Weather app - The package name is gnome-weather, and is available via the Gnome 3 staging ppa.

Gnome music is available via ricotz/testing.

Gnome maps is in the staging ppa.